# VB.NET posting with custom headers

Tags: vb.net

heya I'm required to post a json string to the server but I keep getting the error

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**

I've tried adding these two codes after researching but still got the same error, any ideas?

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

this is my full code, thePostData is a JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dictionary) String

```
Public Function PostToServer(thePostData As String, theConcatted As String, theNonce As String, theTimeStamp As String, theUri as Uri)
    Try
        'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

        Dim theRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(theUri)
        Dim theByteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thePostData)

        theRequest.Method = "POST"
        theRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-Version", "1.1")
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-Method", "SHA256WithRSA")
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-KeyId", theKeyId)
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-Nonce", theNonce)
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-Timestamp", theTimeStamp)
        theRequest.Headers.Add("X-Authentication-Sign", getDataSignature(theConcatted))
        theRequest.ContentLength = theByteArray.Length
        Dim theDataStream As Stream = theRequest.GetRequestStream()
        theDataStream.Write(theByteArray, 0, theByteArray.Length)
        theDataStream.Close()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Function getDataSignature(theData As String)

        Dim theRSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider

        theRSA.FromXmlString(thePrivateKey)
        Dim theRSAFormatter As New RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(theRSA)
        theRSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256")
        Dim theSHhash As New SHA256Managed()
        Dim theSignedHashValue As Byte() = theRSAFormatter.CreateSignature(theSHhash.ComputeHash(New UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(theData)))
        Dim theStringBuilder As New StringBuilder(theSignedHashValue.Length * 2)
        For Each b As Byte In theSignedHashValue
            theStringBuilder.Append(Conversion.Hex(b))
        Next
        Return theStringBuilder.ToString().ToLower()
End Function
```

Comment: In what System is this code run? If it's Windows 7, set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. You need .Net Framework 4.5.2+ (possibly 4.7.2+). Also, set `Option Strict On` in the Project's Properties and/or Visual Studio general Options configuration (`Tools -> Options ->Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults`. Set all to `On` and `Compare = Binary`). Btw, I don't see you reading the Server's response, you should.

Comment: AH thank you, I only just realized I was only running on Framework 4 instead of 4.5.2+. which would explain why `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` was not an option